# How to return data XML schema defination in WCF?

Tags: xml, wcf, xsd, wcf-rest

I have written wcf service which returns data in below format :-

[image: My wcf response]

But instead of this format, i want to return data in below format :-

[image: Client's wcf response]

Can any one share the sample code or refernce link so that i can return data in required format.

Thank you in advance.

Below is my code

```
  [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{


    [OperationContract]

    List<Data123> Get_data();
}

 [DataContract]
public class Data123
{
    [DataMember]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

 public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public List<Data123> Get_data()
    {
        List<Data123> dd = new List<Data123>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data123 d = new Data123();
            d.Name = "Name_" + i.ToString();
            d.State = "State_" + i.ToString();
            d.Mobile = "Mobile_" + i.ToString();
            d.City = "City_" + i.ToString();
            d.Age = "Age_" + i.ToString();
            d.Address = "Address_" + i.ToString();
            dd.Add(d);
        }
        return dd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code, not images. Also, the two images show two completely different schemas - different operations, different parameters. Just create the data contracts, operations for the second service in the same way you created the first. If you simply copied some existing schema and ask for a tutorial for WCF, you'll find a *lot* of tutorials, courses, samples just by googling `WCF tutorial`.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , i have updated sample code of my wcf service.

Comment: Which has nothing to do with either image. It's a completely different schema. What are you asking? SOAP 1.2 is well-defined and WCF is *very* strict about interoperability. Are you trying to produce some non-standard output? Stuff the schema inisde the response ? Use WCF to generate arbitrary XML ?

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7905742/2594240 , i want data similar to this format only here schema and data are in same node and my requirement is my schema should be in child node and data in another child node.

Comment: you should specify that you are trying to create a REST service, as WCF is used for SOAP services. While it *can* generate REST endpoints, Web API is far more advanced and easier to use